# Trying to remove the first column of a document

Tags: vim

I'm using this command below to remove the first column of a document:

```
%s/^[^\t]*\zs\t[^\t]*\ze//g
```

but it says command not found.

Any idea?

Comment: I think there should be a `:` at the start of the command.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "column".

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896637/vim-trying-to-remove-the-first-column-of-a-document).

Answer (score 5):

You need to write it in *command* mode, not *normal*. In other words, press <kbd>:</kbd> first.

```
:%s/^[^\t]*\zs\t[^\t]*\ze//g
```

*Edit:* To remove the first column:

```
:%s/^\S*\s\+//
```

where [`\s` is "whitespace"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#whitespace) and `\S` is its inverse.

Comment: thanks, but now it says the "expression was not found"...Any idea?

Comment: @user35538, do you mean, "pattern not found", right? Where did you found this expression? I don't have much experience with regular expression. You should check it.

Comment: @user35538 how are column separated? if by space this should be enough: :%s/^[^ ]* //g

Answer (score 3):

I don't get an error from your command, but it removes the second column. This command will remove the first column:

```
:%s/^[^\t]*\t\ze[^\t]*//g
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Visual-Block mode.

On the first line of the file, in the first column, hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to get in Visual Block mode, followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>  (moves to the last line of the file) then use <kbd>l</kbd> to move over to the right as far as you want. You should see a visual selection of each column as you move to the right in the file. <kbd>x</kbd>will then delete those columns.

See also: `:he block`

Answer (score 0):

As I already answered on StackOverflow, you might use the following command:

```
:%s/^.//
```

Comment: That will only remove the first character.  I think the OP wants to remove everything up to the first tab.